# attribute error: property object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

About the code: download youtube video using `pytube`.

Code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube

SAVE_PATH = "c:users\pavit\Desktop" #to_do


link=input("enter the link")

try:
    # object creation using YouTube
    # which was imported in the beginning
    yt = YouTube(link)
except:
    print("Connection Error") #to handle exception

mp4files = YouTube.streams.filter()
yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution')[-1].download()

d_video = yt.get(mp4files[-1].extension,mp4files[-1].resolution)
try:

    d_video.download(SAVE_PATH)
except:
    print("Some Error!")
print('Task Completed!')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pavit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python programs\collegepro.py", line 18, in <module>
    mp4files = YouTube.streams.filter()
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Update: I used `yt.streams.filter()`. In this case I got another error saying:

```
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

Comment: Did you  mean `yt.streams.filter()` instead?

Comment: when I did that I'm getting this error:  pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple